# flmoon function in numerical recipies

Tags: c

I have a problem understanding the implementation of the following function in C:

```
#include <math.h>
#define RAD (3.14159265/180.0)
#include "fulmoon.h"


void flmoon(int n, int nph, long *jd, float *frac) {
/*This programs begin with an introductory comment summarizing their purpose and explaining
their calling sequence. This routine calculates the phases of the moon. Given an integer n and
a code nph for the phase desired (nph = 0 for new moon, 1 for first quarter, 2 for full, 3 for last
quarter), the routine returns the Julian Day Number jd, and the fractional part of a day frac
to be added to it, of the nth such phase since January, 1900. Greenwich Mean Time is assumed.*/

int i;
float am,as,c,t,t2,xtra;
c=n+nph/4.0;
t=c/1236.85;
t2=t*t;
printf("jdhdhdhd");
as=359.2242+29.105356*c;
am=306.0253+385.816918*c+0.010730*t2;
*jd=2415020+28L*n+7L*nph;
xtra=0.75933+1.53058868*c+((1.178e-4)-(1.55e-7)*t)*t2;
if (nph == 0 || nph == 2){
    xtra += (0.1734-3.93e-4*t)*sin(RAD*as)-0.4068*sin(RAD*am);
    }
else (nph == 1 || nph == 3){
    xtra += (0.1721-4.0e-4*t)*sin(RAD*as)-0.6280*sin(RAD*am);
    }
i=(int)(xtra >= 0.0 ? floor(xtra) : ceil(xtra-1.0));
*jd += i;
*frac=xtra-i;

}
```

**What I tried**
I made a header file called fulmoon.h as follow:

```
#ifndef header_h
#define header_h

#define myName "Amrit"

void flmoon(int n, int nph, long *jd, float *frac);


#endif
```

Then i called the function flmoon in the main file. What i did't understand are the arguments ***jd** and ***frac**. How could they be input arguments while i am trying to calculate them.?
This example is taken from the book called [Numerical recipes](http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) page 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP first needs to study about them,

Comment: We are here to learn faster. Don't you think that i would take me weeks to learn pointers before even starting my math book.?
I got replies and i understood and now i can progress with my book. @gsamaras

Comment: Hope that's the case and that you don't just cp code. I will retract my close vote (and downvote).

Comment: I had made this example in the past, hope it helps! https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/functions-in-c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments are pointers, so before calling the function, you need to create two local variables that will hold the result. Your input to the function is the pointers, and the function will produce its output in the variables being pointed to. This is a common way to allow a function to return more than one value. Call the function like this:

```
long jdResult;
float fracResult;
flmoon(42, 2, &jdResult, &fracResult); // & creates a pointer to a variable
printf("Results: %l and %f\n", jdResult, fracResult);
```

The variable names could well have been `jd` and `frac`, but I chose different names just to avoid the common misconception that the names of the variables you pass to the function must be the same as the function's parameter names.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters `jd` and `frac` are pointers, meaning you pass in the addresses two local variables which get populated when the function completes

```
long jd;
float frac;
flmoon(1,2,&jd,&frac);
printf("jd=%l, frac=%f\n",jd,frac);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no arguments `*jd` and `*frac`. The `*` is part of the type, designating those parameters (`jd` and `frac`) to be pointers. Looking at the function signature:

```
void flmoon(int n, int nph, long *jd, float *frac);
```

This means that you have to pass some values (`n` and `nph`) as well as those two pointers to that function. The pointers need to point to some valid memory, where the function will then store it's computed results:

```
*jd = // ... dereferencing, i.e. accessing the pointed memory
```

The caller can then access the results (because it's in the memory the pointer passed to the function pointed to):

```
float frac;
long jd;
flmoon(n, nph, &jd, &frac);
// & means address of
// jd and frac now contain the computed values
```

This kind of passing results is often used to pass more than one value as result (since functions can only return of value).

---

Also, I'm quite surprised. Is this the real code used in the book? I wouldn't count that code as "good" ... not something that should be part of some book.